# issue summing columns

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset and I'm trying to get the sums of values. The variables are binary with 0s and 1s.

Somehow, when I run a for loop

```
for (i in 7:39){
agegroup1[53640, i]<-sum(agegroup1[, i])
}
```

The loop processes but everything but the first column would contain nothing but just NA. I tried calling the values up and would see 0 and 1s, as well as checking the class (it returns "integer"). But when adding it all up, R does not work.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked for NA values in the columns you are summing?

Comment: You can check for `NA`s with `any(is.na(agegroup1))`, and you can see where they are with `which(is.na(agegroup1))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cs <- colSums(agegroup1[, 7:39])
```

will give you the vector of column sums without looping (at the R level).

If you have any missing values (`NA`s) in `agegroup1[, 7:39]` then you may want to add `na.rm = TRUE` to the `colSums()` call (or even your `sum()` call).

You don't say what `agegroup1` is or how many rows it has etc, but to finalise what your loop is doing, you then need

```
agegroup1[53640, 7:39] <- cs
```

What was in `agegroup1[53640, ]` *before* you started adding the column sums? `NA`? If so that would explain some behaviour.

We do really need more detail though...

Answer (score 1):

@Gavin Simpson provided a workable solution but alternatively you could use apply. This function allows you to apply a function to the row or column margin.

```
x <- cbind(x1=1, x2=c(1:8), y=runif(8))

# If you wanted to sum the rows of columns 2 and 3
apply(x[,2:3], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)

# If you want to sum the columns of columns 2 and 3
apply(x[,2:3], 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```